# Code only displays "summa cum laude" when ran with numbers between 3.3 and 4. (Very small program - Less than 25 lines)

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm pretty early on in my Visual Basic classes, and I cant for the life of me understand why my code doesn't work. Its an assignment for my class. It seems simple enough, but idk.

Again, any number put in between 3.3 and 4 displays "summa cum laude" 
Am I missing something?
Thanks

```
'Create variables
    Dim strHonors As String
    Dim decGPA As Decimal


    'Get user input
    decGPA = CInt(txtGPA.Text)

    'preform calculations
    If decGPA >= 3.9 Then
        strHonors = " summa cum laude."
    ElseIf decGPA < 3.9 And decGPA >= 3.6 Then
        strHonors = " magna cum laude."
    ElseIf decGPA < 3.6 And decGPA >= 3.3 Then
        strHonors = " cum laude."
    ElseIf decGPA < 3.3 And decGPA >= 2.0 Then
        strHonors = "."

    End If

    'display output
    If decGPA >= 2 And decGPA <= 4 Then
        lblOutput.Text = "You Graduated" & strHonors.ToString()
    Else
        lblOutput.Text = "Incorrect Input. Please Try Again."

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `CInt` to `CDec`:

```
decGPA = CInt(txtGPA.Text)
```

By casting to an integer, you are changing any decimal input into a whole number.

Comment: No worries, good luck with the assignment. If you're like most programmers (myself included), that won't be the last time you say that to yourself after finding a solution to a problem. For similar issues, I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on your `if` & check that the variable is actually what you are expecting.